# Sequelize Model is not associated with model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

<strike>I've been spending hours for nothing.</strike> I've had so many sources, they are all kinda the same, but I just couldn't make my project work.

This question [Sequelize.js - "is not associated to"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50841912/sequelize-js-is-not-associated-to) is so much the same to mine, BUT, this question of mine shouldn't be a duplicate. Because it has certainly a new issue!

To list down my sources, the ones that I've read thoroughly and tried out:

1. [Sequelize.js - "is not associated to"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50841912/sequelize-js-is-not-associated-to)
2. [Sequelize 4.3.2 n:m (many-to-many) association: Unhandled rejection SequelizeEagerLoadingError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45151194/sequelize-4-3-2-nm-many-to-many-association-unhandled-rejection-sequelizeeag)
3. [Link to a book on Google](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=yQnVDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=associate%20user%20and%20role%20sequelize&source=bl&ots=7W5-pZfo0Q&sig=ACfU3U1DE9medNgGKRKdpIAQhu1T8z5Jag&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXo4K9gKrpAhUXBZQKHRMLDdMQ6AEwBnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=associate%20user%20and%20role%20sequelize&f=false)
4. https://medium.com/@eth3rnit3/sequelize-relationships-ultimate-guide-f26801a75554

To add context, I'm trying to provide a route that lets the users get their profile. Every USER has ONLY one ROLE.

Like so:

```
{
  id: 4,
  email: 'adsads@saas.com',
  role: {
     id: 2,
     name: 'admin'
  }
}
```

**Using findOne with WHERE and INCLUDE**

```
exports.getme = (req, res) => {
  db.users.findOne({
    where: { id: req.user.id },
    include: [{
      model: db.roles,
    }]
  })  
  .then(data => {
    res.send(data)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "An error has occured while retrieving data."
    })
  })
}
```

The error that I get is:

> Role is not associated to User!

---

And here are the models, and how I put their respective associations:

**Role.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Role = sequelize.define('Role', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      field: "id"
    },
    role: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    timestamps: false
  });
  Role.associate = function (models) {
    Role.hasMany(models.User, {
      foreignKey: "roleId",
      sourceKey: "id"
    })
  }
  return Role;
};
```

**User.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.BIGINT, allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, unique: true, primaryKey: true },
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {});
  User.associate = function (models) {
    User.belongsTo(models.Role, { 
      foreignKey: "roleId", 
      targetKey: "id"
    });
  }
  return User
}
```

---

Also, when I check the **relations** of my tables, I can only see details in my **USER** table, but none in my **ROLES** table.

[image]
[image]

---

EDIT: Anatoly from the comment section pointed out that it seems `db.users` has no association when the `findOne` fires up. Here's how I setup my models in my `server.js`:

```
....
const db = require("./app/models")

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  db.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    useRoutes()
    seedDB()
  })
} else {
  db.sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
    console.log("Drop and re-sync db.")
    useRoutes()
    seedDB()
  })
}

function useRoutes() {
  console.log("Use routes...")
  require("./app/routes/user/user.routes")(app)
  require("./app/routes/emojis/emojis.routes")(app)
  require("./app/routes/auth/auth.routes")(app)

  const db = require("./app/models")
  // Custom.
  db.op = db.Sequelize.Op
  // Models
  db.appsettings = require("./app/models/appsettings/appsettings.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)
  db.countries = require("./app/models/appsettings/country.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)

  db.users = require("./app/models/user/user.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)
  db.roles = require("./app/models/user/role.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)
  db.userscores = require("./app/models/user/userscore.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)

  db.answers = require("./app/models/game/answer.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)
  db.categories = require("./app/models/game/category.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)
  db.questions = require("./app/models/game/question.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)
  db.useracoomplishedquestions = require("./app/models/game/useracoomplishedquestion.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)
}
```

---

**models/index.js** (generated by Sequelize and I modified it a bit and use `glob` to scan through subfolders easily)

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config')[env];
const db = {};
const glob = require("glob")

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

// Use glob to access model files inside subfolders.
const files = glob.sync(__dirname + "/*/*.js")

files.forEach(file => {
  const model = sequelize['import'](file);
  db[model.name] = model;
})

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: Make sure that `db.users` has non-empty associations prop at the line `db.users.findOne({`

Comment: Hey Anatoly! You again. Thanks for the comment, but I don't get it. Is my findOne query incorrect?

Comment: Long time no see! No, it seems the db.users model has no associations at the moment of executing the `db.users.findOne` line

Comment: Interesting. Could you please check my `server.js` codes above? That's how I setup my db (models/index.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this code

```
// Models
  db.appsettings = require("./app/models/appsettings/appsettings.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)
  db.countries = require("./app/models/appsettings/country.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)

  db.users = require("./app/models/user/user.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)
  db.roles = require("./app/models/user/role.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)
  db.userscores = require("./app/models/user/userscore.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)

  db.answers = require("./app/models/game/answer.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)
  db.categories = require("./app/models/game/category.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)
  db.questions = require("./app/models/game/question.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)
  db.useracoomplishedquestions = require("./app/models/game/useracoomplishedquestion.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)
```

you overridden model definitions registered in models/index.js that's why these models don't have associations. Just remove these lines.

Comment: Why are you registering some models after you import `db` object that registered all models and associations?

Comment: Do you mean in my `server.js` I store models into db.object? Like: `db.users = require(....`? I thought that it would make my life easier importing models in my controllers. Is there any issue with doing it like that?

Comment: You have these models in `db` and you overwrite them by doing `db.appsettings = require("./app/models/appsettings/appsettings.model")(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize)` so that leads to they are losing their associations because you redefine them without calling `associate` method.

Comment: Hey Anatoly. Can you edit the answer? Your suggestion was suggested too by someone on a Facebook group, but his suggestion was clearer for me, nevertheless your comment above should suffice and can be considered as answer. I was indeed overwriting my models! :( It works now!!!!!!!!! I had to spent hours for this issue :/ Let me know once you're done with editing. Thanks!